# How do send multiple recipient in outlook via VBA?

Tags: vba

```
Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim mitOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim recOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim attOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment


Set recOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("ABC@gmail.com") & .Add("123@gmail.com")
    recOutlookRecip.Type = olCC
```

I currently have this but it does not work. I am only allowed to send 1 recipient via

`Set recOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("dave2shalom@gmail.com") 
        recOutlookRecip.Type = olCC`

I need to hard code the email addresses. Any help will be greatly appreciated :D
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `To` line you can add delimited list of recipients. You can also do

```
.Recipients.Add "dave2shalom@gmail.com;ABC@gmail.com"
```

Code:

```
Public Sub SendEmail()
    Dim OutMail As MailItem, OutApp As Outlook.Application

    Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "dave2shalom@gmail.com;ABC@gmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Display
        Stop '<==Delete me later

    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```